# Proxy/gateway for HTTP binding

Tags: http, proxy, xmpp

I have following infrastructure and want to provide an online web chat (on server 1) using our internal xmpp server (server 2), which is running an Openfire server.

wan <----> server 1 <----> server 2

Server 1 can only reach server 2 over a HTTP proxy. So I need a possibility to get a HTTP binding or something else on server 1, which provides the bindings for a web chat like JWChat or Co.
I think a simple redirect to the HTTP binding on server 2 would be good, but I don't know how.

Perhaps there is another possibility, thanks for any advices.

EDIT:
The nginx configuration is now like the following:

```
server {
    listen       8000;
    server_name  server1 localhost;

    location ~ ^/http-bind {
        proxy_pass http://server2:8085;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://proxy:3128;
    }
}
```

But the following commands doesn't work correctly:

```
-bash-4.1# wget http://localhost:8000
--2012-02-06 10:57:14--  http://localhost:8000/
Resolving localhost... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:8000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 400 Bad Request
2012-02-06 10:57:14 ERROR 400: Bad Request.

-bash-4.1# wget http://localhost:8000/http-bind
--2012-02-06 10:57:21--  http://localhost:8000/http-bind
Resolving localhost... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:8000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 502 Bad Gateway
2012-02-06 10:57:21 ERROR 502: Bad Gateway.
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically server 1 will be running:

1. A proxy
2. A webserver running your chat app.

Let's assume nginx as a proxy running on port 80, and your choice of a webserver running on port 8080. Also assume that your web client will bind to `/http-bind`. Your nginx config will then contain:

```
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  server1;

        location ~ ^/http-bind {
            proxy_pass http://server2:5280;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
        }

    }
```

Adapt accordingly for some other proxy.

Comment: Can I configure nginx that it uses a proxy to reach the server 2?

Comment: Sure, nginx will just proxy to your other proxy. Not what the point of that is, but yes you can

Comment: But nginx have to use a proxy to reach server 2.

Comment: And that's fine. nginx IS also a proxy, if you rely on some other proxy to reach server 2 you can do that. If you can rely on nginx to play that role you don't need a second one.

Comment: I have no chance to switch. I have to use the internal proxy to reach server 2 and I can't change that. :) With Google I can't find a lot of details about that use case.

Comment: All you have to do is to configure location / with a proxy_pass to your proxy url. There's no magic, it's like rewriting. Alternatively use your proxy and configure it to redirect /http-bind to ejabberd, as in the nginx config.

Comment: Thanks, I have a problem with the configuration, see my question.

Comment: It make no difference, I have tested it with Apache server and it doesn't work. I shall get an index file, but I got the bad gateway.

Comment: Again. Does ejabberd listen on 8085? Do you see ejabberd responding at server2:8085/http-bind without the proxy?

Comment: Dude I quit. After 2 days of back and forth, you remember to give an essential piece of info such as that you use a different server to the one I assume from the beginning? Please next time tag your question appropriately. Sorry don't mean to be rude but I had enough.

Comment: There is no information about which server is used. XMPP is given and there a lot of implementation of servers. So I don't know why do you think it was ejabberd. I had never used that tag.